# Computationally Heavy Method in Modal View

Tags: python, class, flask, jinja2

I have a simple `Person` class with a `name` attribute and some computational heavy method called `computationally_heavy_method`:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    def computationally_heavy_method(self) -> str:
        # do lots of stuff and then return the result.
        return ''
```

I have a *large* list of `Person` instances:

```
people = [Person(name='Alex')] * 1000
```

which I pass to jinja template as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', people=people)
```

and the index.html file looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {% for person in people %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                {{ person | safe }}
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">{{ person }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            {{ person.computationally_heavy_method() }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
<html>
```

So essentially I have a list of buttons representing the people, which when you click presents a modal view.

However, the modal view is super computationally heavy because of the repeated calls to the `computationally_heavy_method` method.

**Is there any way to make the modal view when it's needed (i.e. when the button is actually pressed) rather than for all 1000 `Person` instances?**

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Where is the end of the `{% for person in people %}` loop?

Comment: @TomDalton I've added the `endfor` to the question

Comment: @TomDalton Do you have any suggestions for how I can take out the `<div class="modal ... ` section such that it's only rendered when the button is clicked?